# Delphi 5 to 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, crc

I used same function ( **OneWayEncrypt(edit1.Text)** ) in Delphi 5 and 2010.
Why the results are different? (Or how can I give the same results from Delphi 2010?)

```
uses Sysutils, Windows, Dialogs, classes;

function OneWayEncrypt(AStr: string): string;
PROCEDURE CalcCRC32 (p:  pointer; ByteCount:  DWORD; VAR CRCvalue:  DWORD);

implementation

const 
  table:  ARRAY[0..255] OF DWORD = 
  (
    //table consts are here
  );

PROCEDURE CalcCRC32(p: pointer; ByteCount: DWORD; VAR CRCvalue: DWORD);
VAR
  i: DWORD;
  q: ^Byte;
BEGIN
  q := p;
  FOR i := 0 TO ByteCount - 1 DO
  BEGIN
    CRCvalue := (CRCvalue SHR 8) XOR table[q^ XOR (CRCvalue AND $000000FF)];
    INC(q);
  END
END;

function OneWayEncrypt(AStr: string): string;
var
  dwCrc: DWORD;
  s: string;
begin
  dwCrc := $FFFFFFFF; 
  s := 'X' + AStr + '7F';
  CalcCRC32(Addr(s[1]), Length(s), dwCrc);
  result := IntToHex(dwCrc, 8);
end;
```

Comment: How is this an encryption function? It's a lossy hashing  function using CRC32 to calculate very weak hashes.

Comment: Interesting Points: When you run this code, is the result of OneWayEncrypt a eight-digit value with the most significant four digits all being zero? Because when I run this code here, using some table that I made up myself for your constants above, which are size DWORD, for some reason, I get this result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you aware that `string` refers to a Unicode string in D2010, while it refers to AnsiString in versions < D2009? That should be the source of your problem.

So you have two choices:

- You could replace all appearances of `string` with `AnsiString`. This should give you the same results as in D5, of course without Unicode support
- You could refactor your code. I guess that the pointer-"hacking" is the crucial part here. But I have to admit, I didn't take the time to fully understand the code ;-) 
  (It could very well be that your code can't be used with Unicode anyways, due to the 255 consts = ISO8859?)

Comment: Exactly. Read Nick Hodge's "Delphi in a Unicode World" papers at the EMbarcadero/Codegear Developers Network website.

Answer (score 4):

D2010 (and D2009) use Unicode strings (widestrings), so the character size is different (bytes). Try switching all references of string to AnsiString.

Comment: And Char to AnsiChar, and PChar to PAnsichar.  Except that a blind search and replace without knowing what you're doing will be wrong in some places (lets say 10%), and right in others (lets say 90%). So you have to do some thinking, and learning, and make smart decisions, not blindly apply rules, to port upwards.

Comment: In this guy's case, that would be one step forward, and two steps back. see my answer

Answer (score 3):

Minimal port, one line change:

```
  // old code:
  CalcCRC32(Addr(s[1]), Length(s), dwCrc);

  // delphi 2010 code:
  CalcCRC32( PAnsiChar(AnsiString(s)), Length(s), dwCrc);
```

Please be aware that any unicode content in the unicode "String" will be lost, but any ANSI (A-Z, 1,3,4, you know) codepoints you used before, for example "Hello", should work just like before. Since this is a CRC32 algorithm, it could do a CRC32 on a UTF8 encoding of the string too, easily.